# After what I think was an abusive edit should I flag and re-edit back or just flag and wait?

Tags: discussion, edits, abuse

I got a comment about a mistake in one [old answer of mines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36970773/320726) that I think was not a mistake, and made it clear instead that the commenter had a quite common misconception about a specific technical issue (can in C or C++ `sizeof(char)` be different from 1?).

I edited my answer adding a deeper explanation of why I used certain terms instead of others and told the commenter s/he was wrong. After a while I noticed my answer was changed in content and spirit and I was also sort of menaced by a 300k+, not sure why. I flagged the comment but I'm not sure if I should re-edit back my answer or not and wait instead...

As far as I remember it's the first time someone changes the **content** of an answer of mines (isn't downvoting the procedure in these cases?) and I'm not sure about what to do...

Comment: yeah, i mean, just roll it back. it's your answer.

Comment: The edit was technically correct, looking at the documentation for the language. That said, it's your answer. Within the TOS, you have final say over what it says. You could be a little less condescending in your comments though. (The worst offending comment is gone now...)

Comment: @Cerbrus: the edit was not correct. If someone thinks that my answer is wrong they've to downvote it to oblivion, not to change it to what they think it's a correct answer. It would have been different if the correction was about a typo... but the edit actually changed the spirit and removed the discussion about how `sizeof(char)` is indeed always 1 even when chars have more than 8 bits.

Comment: Strictly speaking, those edits, if made by a user without the edit privilege, would've been rejected by most reviewers. Those types of edits change the answer to a degree where it's better to just post a separate answer. But the editor decided to correct your answer instead, which the documentation points to is correct. I'm not looking to drag this into a debate on what's wrong and what isn't, but that edit is NOT abusive. It was made in good faith and as an attempt to help you as the answerer. It's also backed up by the documentation, so if you call it a misconception, I say [citation needed]

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Comments are not for extended discussion around the argument about whether it's against the CoC to edit a user's post. Please post a new meta question about it if you want to discuss that in particular.  Please keep the comments to clarifications about the user's post and not into an extended discussion on the idea of 'ownership'.  They may be good arguments but no one is going to find those in this debate between two users in the comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I love when people edit my answers, because this is what Stack Overflow is all about, collective effort to bring good information to future users.

True, sometimes the edit may destroy what the intention of the answer was, but fortunately it's very easy to rollback.

> After what I think was an abusive edit should I flag and re-edit back or just flag and wait?

I would assume good faith and just rollback the edit as long as there is not a pattern, since also the moderator can not do much more.

According to me you should only raise a custom flag if:

- The user **clearly** vandalize your post. I know you felt this, but presuming good faith, in this case I think the user simply was convinced that they where improving/correcting your answer.
- The users continues to rollback (avoid rollback war).
- The user targets multiple of your answers with what you feel are bad edits.

Give to the moderators sufficient proof that the user is abusing the edit feature before you raise the flag.

Comment: I didn't find the edit abusive, but it changed my answer removing what I think was an important point. I flagged the comment containing the "watch your tone" message because I found that sort of menacing (may be I just saw a "... or otherwise..." meaning in it that wasn't present). The reaction to me using "watch your tone" in the comments of this discussion however made clear for me that it is indeed a phrase that doesn't sound too friendly (I'm not a native english speaker, so I can make this kind of mistakes easily).

Answer (score 16):

The content of the answer was not substantively changed. All I did was correct a technical term, and remove some meta-discussion that had been triggered by an argument in the comments. The actual answer remained the same. I don't go around substantively altering people's posts. Calling it "abusive" is a gross overreaction.

Regardless, all you had to do was roll it back if you were unhappy with it, like any other edit.

As for "menacing" you, no. You wrote an extremely rude comment to Tiphaine (now deleted), and my "watch your tone" suffix (three words appended to an otherwise technical comment) was an accompaniment to the flag I raised on your comment, hoping that you might change the manner in which you were engaging in discourse. I'm sorry to find that this attempt failed.

Comment: For posterity, the "menacing comment" follows. I've deleted it at source because it was in response to another comment that has since been flagged away. However, I did not want anyone to think that I was hiding it, so here it is: _"A char is a byte. Calling it a "character" too used to be acceptable but is now too ambiguous to be wise, as the comments above show. Also, watch your tone."_ I only wish I could remember the multi-sentence _ad hominem_ diatribe on competence and "not feeling too bad about your misconceptions" directed at Tiphaine that preceded it.

Answer (score 2):

Edits to a answer should respect the Original Poster's intent of the answer (that is, you can't change someone's post to say the opposite of what they said).

You're welcome to edit an answer to elaborate or to help fix up spelling or content errors, but if your 'fixes' end up going against what the author was saying in the first place, they shouldn't be made.

If someone does that to your answer, feel free to roll it back.  It's also helpful to use the 'edit summary' on the edit screen to indicate why you're rolling it back.

If a user continues to edit it even after you've rolled it back, please flag your answer with 'other' and explain to the moderators what's going on and we'll step in.

It's really important to flag, and not get into an edit war with someone.  Edit wars make both parties look bad, a flag makes it look like you're trying to resolve the issue amicably.

Similiar guidance can be found in these Meta Questions:

[Is it acceptable to edit an answer in ways that fundamentally change it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269353/is-it-acceptable-to-edit-an-answer-in-ways-that-fundamentally-change-it)

[If someone edits my post, can I rollback the edits if I don't like the edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272895/if-someone-edits-my-post-can-i-rollback-the-edits-if-i-dont-like-the-edits)

[What could I do if I don't agree with my edit rollback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222283/what-could-i-do-if-i-dont-agree-with-my-edit-rollback)

[My accepted answer was modified drastically. Is this allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321530/my-accepted-answer-was-modified-drastically-is-this-allowed)

(H/t to [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) for providing these links in a comment)

Comment: Surely we have a faq entry for this already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit and our help center, neither address what not to edit. I'm actually surprised that hasn't been addressed in a faq.